# recursion order why does it go up?

Tags: recursion

So help me understand how recursion works. Why does the following code print out 1,2,3,4,5,6 in that order? Why not 6 downward why is it going up?

```
public class Recursion {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Recursion r = new Recursion();
        r.blag(6);
    }

    int blag(int num){
        if(num!=0){
            blag(num-1);
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        return 10;
    }

}
```

OR

something like this:

```
int getTriNum(int num){
    if(num==1){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return(num+getTriNum(num-1));
    }
}
```

Please explain how it comes up with number 21 if you input 6 for num.

Answer (score 0):

Calls the recursion before the print. Once the recursion get's to num=1. The returned value of 10 is ignored and the value of 1 is printed. Then returns to the call when num was equal to 2. As the function calls return. They print out in numerical order.
    blag(num-1);
    System.out.println(num)

In the second example, the numbers are added when returned. 6+5+4+3+2+1 = 21

Answer (score 0):

In `blag()`, you have this code:

```
if (num != 0){
    blag(num - 1);
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Notice that `blag(num - 1)` is called again recursively **before** the number is printed. So, the numbers print in the order of smaller to larger.